# how to get path param from ContainerRequestContext

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I want to apply authorization filter for my REST API endpoint, and the filter need path parameter to do the filtering. here is my endpoint and code:

endpoint:

```
curl --url 'localhost:80/reports/resources/org/12345/product/111 ' --request GET --header 'Authorization: <token here>'
```

resource code:

```
@Path("/resources")
public class MyResource extends AbstractResource {
...
    @GET
    @Path("/org/{orgId}/product/{productId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @RoleAuthenticated
    public Response getResourcesReport(@PathParam("orgId") String orgId,
                                       @PathParam("productId") String productId,
                                       @Context HttpHeaders headers){....}
```

Filter:

```
@PreMatching
@RoleAuthenticated
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathparam = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();   <--  return empty map  
}
```

I was expecting `requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters()` returned map of the following:

```
orgId 12345
productId 111
```

how come it return an empty map ? and How can I get path parameters from `ContainerRequestContext`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You used a `@PreMatching` annotation on the filter.

The Javadoc says:

> In case the filter should be applied at the pre-match extension point,
>   i.e. before any request matching has been performed by JAX-RS runtime,
>   the filter MUST be annotated with a @PreMatching annotation.

So the filter is invoked before the incoming request has been matched to a particular resource by the JAX-RS runtime, and therefore the path parameters are empty.

So I guess you need to remove the `@PreMatching` annotation.

Comment: you are right! after I remove @PreMatching, it works