# How to change path parameters from ContainerRequestContext in @PreMatching filter?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, jax-rs

I want to change path parameter in ContainerRequestFilter

```
    @Provider
    @PreMatching
    public class XssFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
     @Override
        public void filter( ContainerRequestContext request ) throws IOException {
            cleanPathParams(request);
        }

   private void cleanPathParams( ContainerRequestContext request )
    {
        UriBuilder builder = request.getUriInfo().getRequestUriBuilder();
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> queries = request.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();
        cleanParams(builder, queries); //empty if there is a @PreMatching annotation
        request.setRequestUri( builder.build() ); // Method could be called only in pre-matching request filter.
    }      
 }
```

With @PreMatching:

1. I dont't have map of path parameters (it's empty) but can save

Due to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35214503/4274360 answer i removed @PreMatching annotation but now:

2. I have map of path parameters by i can't save it (post-matching)

There is any way to replace URI params in @PreMatching filter?

Comment: If it doesn't know the resource, then it can't possibly know the path parameters. That's just how it is with a PRE-matching filter.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this particular problem by changing the business logic (rejected the request with xss instead of escaping parameters from xss payload).

The solution that replace path and query parameters is to configure Aspcects to call just after API method was call but before the body of API was executed (imagine as first line in API).

```
private void api(@PathParam("name") String name) {
      //configure aspects to run here (1st line) - at this point we got parameters and can write them

      //body of endpoint
      return;
}
```